# Keeping track of number of occurrences of each value between field separator

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to gather information on the number of occurrences of each individual value in a file. I would like to output the value, the number of times it appears in the entire file, and count the number of times each value occurs between a field separator: `"---"`
Input:

```
textfile.txt
```

Output:

```
indexed_value - 50 - 12
```

I've begun by using [this program on gnu.org][1] to index a value and sum it's frequency but have not been able to get any further.

Working with an older version of mawk.

```
awk    '{
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            freq[$i]++
    }END {
            for (word in freq)
                printf "%s\t%d\n", word, freq[word]
    }' ./dir/file.txt | sort -f
```

Which outputs

```
indexed_value - 50
```

For tracking the number of fields:

```
awk -F "___" '
{ count[NF]++ }
END{
    for(num in count) 
        printf("%s\t%d\n", num, count[num]) 
}'
```

Output:

```
number of fields separated by ---     22
number of new lines                   323
```

I just need the number separated by the specified field separator. How do I put these two commands into one?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking questions on text processing, please always include a (possibly anonymized) example of the input to be processed, along with the desired output.

Comment: Also include your attempt at solving the problem yourself. Provide your input, output, and code as text, not as links or images.

Comment: You've added 3 versions of output, but haven't shown us the input that you'd get that output from. It's much easier for us to help you write a tool to parse some input if you show us the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following variables:

letter: t

filename: terminal

field seperator: p

The following command will give you everything you're asking without mawk:

echo " t - $(grep -oi t terminal | wc -l) - $(grep -i t*p terminal | wc -l)"

If you want to make it case-sensitive, remove the "i" flags from the grep commands.

Comment: That's not what the OP is trying to do and that approach can't be modified to do what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question.